# What's not right about "Why did all the miracles stoped"?

Tags: discussion

On the face of it, the question, [Why did all the miracles stoped?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/10271/3487), doesn't seem to have consumed much effort before and after it was posted, in term of the *question*, not the answer and comments it brought about.

The question in it's present state seems to be just a random claim which is not backed up by any reference and is limited to the scope of the a person's social exposure and beliefs (what (s)he considers to be a *miracle* etc), which too is not known. Therefore this question is definitely going to draw debate and slight, which is quite evident from the comments section under both the question and the answers.

As mentioned, the question can't, strictly and adequately, be answered and will mostly draw *just information* on the topic.

The question seems very weakly connected to Islam, which this site is about.

It is too broad, and opinion based.

How can this question be *improved*? Is it *salvageable*? Why should it be *considered on-topic* here? What more is *fundamentally lacking* in the question? Where am I *not right* in the points mentioned above?

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem with the post is, as you pointed out in the first paragraph, that it doesn't seem to have consumed much effort.

I don't think it really falls into a closeworthy category right now; I can see the arguments for off-topic, too broad or too opinion-based, but it's mostly just sitting in the gray area of not-yet-defined site policy.  It looks like a clear and answerable (if simple) question — especially now that it's been edited — it just expects a disproportionate amount of effort be put into answers than was (apparently) put into the question.

I reckon this is the type of thing that site voting should sort out.  If enough people feel that it doesn't show enough effort, or is not useful, or otherwise just isn't worth being answered on the site, the downvotes will remove it from the front page so it won't bother anybody.

Answer (score 1):

I edited the question to be more in conformance with site and SE guidelines and re-opened it. I think it's a good question as far as subject matter goes. Clearly there wasn't much effort put into it in the beginning, but other users can feel free to communicate with the asker and expand on it if they feel it's worth their time.

Comment: I still have reservation towards the aptness of the question *"Do phenomena on this scale happen anymore?"* on [islam.se]. People can have largely different ideas and/or *opinions* about *scale*. So answers to this question have the potential of varying largely based on that particular answerer's idea/opinion rather than varying based on a particular group ["that identify themselves as Muslim"](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Apart from that how is this particular question (although an interesting one for debate, moot), upon which the ensuing one depends, is relevant to Islam?

Comment: @hus787 edited and specified further :)